# preg_replace only if not in a block

Tags: php, preg-replace

I try to use preg_replace to replace bracket with an underscore except when these bracket are in a code block

Exemple :

```
this is my {text}
And this is <code>if (true) { echo "hello world" }</code>
And also a multine line one 
<code>
if (true) { echo "hello world" }
</code>
Another {my super text}
```

I must output :

```
this is my _text_
And this is <code>if (true) { echo "hello world" }</code>
And also a multine line one 
<code>
if (true) { echo "hello world" }
</code>
Another _my super text_
```

Thanks

Comment: So show what you've attempted so far. We (maybe) fix code you've written. we're not here to do your job for you.

Comment: Your text is not a regular language. Therefore, you cannot parse it properly with a regular expression. You need to parse it linearly, manually.

Comment: Use some other method to extract the non-code sections of the string. Then do the `preg_replace` on that, and put it back together with the code blocks.

Comment: Copy pasting some bad non working regex, yeah very interesting, yeah you can fix it by rewriting them. No I was not asking for a simple answer, I was hoping for an explanation on how I can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got it, need more test but seems to be ok

```
preg_replace("<code(?:\s+\w+)*>.*?</code>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\{|\})is", "_", $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the code blocks from the text blocks first. You could use a combination of [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to do that.